# Relative Referencing - Steps

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do relative referencing for a specific column (in Sheet "OA") where I need to retrieve the content of cells in a new sheet in steps of 110

e.g,

```
=OA!$AB217
=OA!$AB327
=OA!$AB437
```

Rather than manually code the formula in each cell, trying to drag the cells so the address could be dynamically generated.

On the above example, when I drag the cell, I am unable to get

```
=OA!$AB547
```

but getting

```
=OA!$AB220
```

I also tried to code it this way, "=OA!$AB($107+(n*$110))" where when the n values naturally incremented during the drag, I will get the right formula.

E.g

```
=OA!$AB($107+(1*$110)) => =OA!$AB217
=OA!$AB($107+(2*$110)) => =OA!$AB327
=OA!$AB($107+(3*$110)) => =OA!$AB437
=OA!$AB($107+(4*$110)) => =OA!$AB547
```

Unfortunately the format is not accepted by excel.

Could you please give me a hint what mistake I could have made ? My search on the internet have not been fruitful.

rgds
Saravanan K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the "[Indirect](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323)" function.  Assemble a text string with the address of the cell you want, and call =indirect("string").  You can use the "&" operator to combine static strings with variables.

I've created a workbook with Sheet1 and OA
OA!A1:A1000 contain the numbers.

Sheet1!C1 contains 1
Sheet1!C2 contains 100

Sheet1!B1 contains =INDIRECT("OA!$A"&C1)
Sheet1!B2 contains =INDIRECT("OA!$A"&C2)